# Horizontally align figures using parbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats

I have 6 images and I need to align them in a 2x3 matrix with 3 images on 1 line and 3 on the other. This is the code so far which vertically aligns all 6 images. How do I change it?

```
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
 \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_1.png}
  Raw Image
\end{center}
}}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
\parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_2.png}
  Gaussian Smoothing
\end{center}
 }}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
\parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_3.png}
  Eigenvalues
\end{center}
}}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
\parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_4.png}
  Seeds
\end{center}
}}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
\parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_5.png}
  Labeled Seeds
\end{center}
}}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
\parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_6.png}
  Boxes
\end{center}
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

With your approach, you're heading in the right direction. But you define a `\parbox[\columnwidth]` for each of your graphics. So you explicitly tell LaTeX to put every picture on a separate line. Just remove 4 of your "big" `\parbox`es and it works the way  you planned it to.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{
  \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_1.png}
    Raw Image
  }
  \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_2.png}
    Gaussian Smoothing
  }
  \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_3.png}
    Eigenvalues
}}

\parbox{\columnwidth}{
  \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_4.png}
    Seeds
  }
  \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_5.png}
    Labeled Seeds
  }
  \parbox{0.3\columnwidth}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img/preproc_6.png}
    Boxes
}}
\end{document}
```

By the way, I recommend to use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in an environment such as a `\parbox`. Refer to [l2tabu](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) for this and also see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)